# Python program to copy only specific rows from excel file copying all the rows

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I am trying to copy only specific rows from one excel file to another using python. `temp_list`  has the row numbers that I want to copy only. But it seems like it is copying all the rows. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("file.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
temp_list = [1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,19,26]
book1 = copy(book)
sheet1=book1.get_sheet(0)
totalcols=sheet.ncols
k=0

for j in temp_list: #for rows
    for i in range(0,totalcols):
        try:
            value=sheet.cell_value(j,i)

            sheet1.write(k,i,value)
        except IndexError:
            continue
    k=k+1
book1.save("Gibberish_Removed.xls")
```

Comment: You copy the book to book1. Dont you want to create a new empty book instead oft calling `copy(book)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use "xlwt" package for your writing.

```
import xlrd
from xlwt import Workbook

book = xlrd.open_workbook("file.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
temp_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 19, 26]
book1 = Workbook()
sheet1 = book1.add_sheet('test', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
total_cols = sheet.ncols
k = 0
for j in temp_list: #for rows
    for i in range(0, total_cols):
        value = sheet.cell_value(j-1,i)
        sheet1.write(k, i, value)
    k += 1
book1.save("Gibberish_Removed.xls")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in

```
 book1 = copy(book)
 sheet1 = book1.get_sheet(0)
```

and then

```
sheet1.write(chosen_values) #chosen value is value at index, (k,i)
```

This will just overwrite the chosen value to (k,i), *but since you copied sheet1 from book*, it will have other rows as well.
You need to start with a blank sheet1.